# Can I customize Wechaty UrlLink title

Tags: node.js, wechaty

Wechaty is a Bot SDK for Wechat Individual Account which can help you create a bot in 6 lines of javascript, with cross-platform support including Linux, Windows, Darwin(OSX/Mac) and Docker. see: https://github.com/chatie/wechaty

I want to send URL Link using wechaty, can I customize this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Relate doc:  https://docs.chatie.io/v/zh/faq#url-message

Example code in wechaty: https://github.com/Chatie/wechaty/blob/master/src/user/message.ts#L471

```
const linkPayload = new UrlLink ({
         description : 'WeChat Bot SDK for Individual Account, Powered by TypeScript, Docker, and Love',
         thumbnailUrl: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/25162437?s=200&v=4',
         title       : 'Welcome to Wechaty',
         url         : 'https://github.com/chatie/wechaty',
       })
       await msg.say(linkPayload)
```

You can change the title you like.